# Variable does not live long enough: matching Option type

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm using getopts, and I was previously getting a value from a flag like this:

```
let file = matches.opt_str("f").unwrap();
let file_path = Path::new(&file);
```

But, I would like to handle the possible errors better, by making the path optional. This is my new code:

```
let file = matches.opt_str("f");
let file_path = match file {
    Some(f) => Some(Path::new(&f)),
    None    => None
}
```

But, when I try to compile this code, I get the error `'f' does not live long enough`. I'm completely stumped.

Heres the MCVE of my code:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let foo = Some("success".to_string());
    let string = match foo {
        Some(s) => Some(Path::new(&s)),
        None    => None
    };
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:35
  |
5 |     let string = match foo {
  |         ------ borrow later stored here
6 |         Some(s) => Some(Path::new(&s)),
  |                                   ^^ - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                                   |
  |                                   borrowed value does not live long enough
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue arises because you are *taking ownership* of the contents of the `Option` in your match with the binding `s` (which uses *bind-by-value*). However, since nothing uses `s` after the match arm, it would be dropped and cause a invalid reference, so it's prevented.

Instead, you could *bind-by-reference*:

```rust
let string = match foo {
    Some(ref s) => Some(Path::new(s)),
    None        => None,
};
```

You could also get an `Option<&T`> from the `Option<T>` using [`as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```rust
let string = match foo.as_ref() {
    Some(s) => Some(Path::new(s)),
    None    => None,
};
```

I'd probably use the last solution coupled with [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```rust
let string = foo.as_ref().map(Path::new);
```

In modern Rust, you can leverage *match ergonomics* and match on the `&Option<T>`:

```rust
let string = match &foo {
    Some(s) => Some(Path::new(s)),
    None    => None,
};
```

See also:

- [Why does pattern matching on &Option<T> yield something of type Some(&T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55625001/155423)

Comment: I'd use [`PathBuf::from()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#impl-From%3CString%3E) instead of `Path`.