# When to add `Option::as_ref` when matching?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a binary search tree. The complete code [is on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f9963d709971344a63b60dca7f23683).

```rust
type Link<K, V> = Option<Box<Node<K, V>>>;

struct Node<K, V> {
    key: K,
    val: V,
    left: Link<K, V>,
    right: Link<K, V>,
    n: usize, // nodes in subtree rooted here
}
pub struct BST<K, V> {
    root: Link<K, V>, // root of BST
}
```

In the `_delete()` helper method, I found it is necessary to add `as_ref` when matching in the `Equal` arm:

```rust
fn _delete(x: &mut Link<K, V>, k: &K) {
    if let Some(node) = x {
        match k.cmp(&node.key) {
            Ordering::Less => { Self::_delete(&mut node.left, k);
                node.n = Self::_size(&node.left) + Self::_size(&node.right) + 1;                       
            },
            Ordering::Greater => { Self::_delete(&mut node.right, k);
                node.n = Self::_size(&node.left) + Self::_size(&node.right) + 1;   
            },
            Ordering::Equal => {
                match (node.left.as_ref(), node.right.as_ref()) {
                    (None, None) => *x = None,
                    (Some(_), None) => *x = node.left.take(),
                    (None, Some(_)) => *x = node.right.take(),
                    (Some(_), Some(_)) => {
                        *x = Self::extract_min(&mut node.right);
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace the `Equal` arm with following code, it is correct in the syntax sense (although it is wrong logically)

```rust
Ordering::Equal => {
    match node.left {
        Some(_) => {},
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

I think it must be a borrow-checking problem, but I cannot figure out the difference between a plain variable (i.e., `node.left`) and a tuple (i.e., `(node.left, node.right)`) while matching. Why and when to use `as_ref` while matching?

Comment: The most important bit of imformation about code that doesn't compile is the error message. It appears you think it's the least important information. :)

Comment: `(foo, bar)` takes ownership of `foo` and `bar` to move them into the newly-created tuple. You don't have ownership to give away. See also [Cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338659/155423); [Why does pattern matching on &Option<T> yield something of type Some(&T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55625001/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching a value does not require ownership of the value, and won't move the value per se. Constructing a tuple `(a, b)` out of two values will move `a` and `b` into the tuple, though. The match expression itself does not cause this error. It's the construction of the tuple that does.

You are not allowed to move `node.left` and `node.right` into the tuple, since you only have a mutable reference to `node`. Adding `.as_ref()` solves the problem – copying references to the values inside `node.left` and `node.right` is fine.

Comment: I'd advocate for `(&a, &b)`.

Comment: See also [Why does pattern matching on &Option<T> yield something of type Some(&T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55625001/155423)