# How does `mut` work when matching on a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, match

In the below program I am trying to understand the intricacies of the `match` statements when `mut`, `&` do come in. Beyond that there is no other scope in terms of any functionality.

To figure out the type of the variable, I used the variable to call a function `checkout(n:i32)`. The compiler now will complain that checkout expects `i32`, but whereas the program is passing some other type. I am a newbie and this was the one way i thought we could figure out types of a variable which we don't explicitly mention.

```
fn checkout (k5:i32) {}

fn main() {
    let k5 = "learning rust".to_string();
    let k1 = Some(k5);
    match &mut k1 {
        Some(mut n) => {
            checkout(n);
            println!("the idea is {} {} ", n, n);
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

If I compile the program, the following error message is got

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> suds12.rs:9:35
  |
9 |           Some(mut n)=> {checkout(n);println!("the idea is {} {} ",n,n);},
  |                                   ^ expected `i32`, found struct `String`
```

The above clearly demonstrates that when `mut n` is present within `Some`, then the type of `n` is found to be that of `String`.

However if the program changes from `Some (mut n)` to `Some(n)`, then the type of `n` is said to be `&mut string`. This can be again seeing by compiling the program with Some(n) and the error message is given below

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> suds12.rs:9:31
  |
9 |           Some(n)=> {checkout(n);println!("the idea is {} {} ",n,n);},
  |                               ^ expected `i32`, found `&mut String`
```

Here we can easily see that `n` is of type `&mut String`.

Why this is so?

Comment: *"If i comple the above program"* - the program [does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea81c0898039acf8192d6d8d586a7620), `k1` should be marked `mut` and I'm guessing the other error is the source of this question? I'm asking because you did not mention any error.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you obtain the types?

Comment: @kmdreko: I have edited the program to mention how i figured out the type along with th compilation errors.

Comment: Are you asking what the `mut` keyword does in a match statement? As far as I know it just derefs a mutable reference for exhaustiveness and convenience, no?

Answer (score 6):

The confusion why `Some(n)` binds `n` to `&mut String` but `Some(mut n)` binds `n` to `String` is due to how match ergonomics were implemented.

Prior to this, `match` arms for references had to be much more explicit:

```
let mut k = Some("string".to_string());
match &mut k {
    &mut Some(ref mut x) => {},
    &mut None => {},
};
```

<sup>compile with version 1.25.0 or prior to test out the behavior</sup>

Lets focus on all the potential bindings for `x`:

- `x`: would bind to the value directly, yielding a `String`
- `ref x`: would bind to the value by reference, yielding a `&String`
- `ref mut x`: would bind to the value by mutable reference, yielding a `&mut String`
- `mut x`: is the same as `x`, it would bind to the value directly, yielding a `String`, with the only difference that `n` can be mutated

This understandably was tedious to write so [RFC 2005: Match Ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) was designed to make the typical cases simpler to use. To accomplish that, it introduced [binding modes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#binding-modes) where if the value was being pattern-matched on was a immutable or mutable reference, it would automatically infer bindings to `x` to be `ref x` or `ref mut x` respectively. So the above code could now be written as:

```
let mut k = Some("string".to_string());
match &mut k {
    Some(x) => {},
    None => {},
};
```

Much nicer.

However, the original syntax still exists and is usable even with the new binding modes in effect. For example, you can still use `ref` in a binding on a value to only bind to its reference. Or if you're already matching on a mutable reference you can use just `ref` to override that the binding to be immutable instead of mutable. Using any of `ref`/`ref mut`/`mut` would override the binding mode.

Do you see where this is going? Using `Some(x)` will use the `ref mut` binding mode since it is being matched on a `&mut Option<_>` and therefore bind `x` to `&mut String`. But using `Some(mut x)` the binding mode is overridden and will therefore bind `x` to `String` directly, with `x` being mutable.

See also:

- [Why does pattern matching on &Option<T> yield something of type Some(&T)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625001/why-does-pattern-matching-on-optiont-yield-something-of-type-somet)
- [Why is `ref` used instead of an asterisk in pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184472/why-is-ref-used-instead-of-an-asterisk-in-pattern-matching)
- [Weird type when pattern matching references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731788)
- [Rust issue: Match ergonomics means bindings have different types inside and outside of patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64586)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answers my question.